# Add numbers through the columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write the code that will add the numbers from 2 seperate rows across the columns. On the row 4 and row 6 I store an array of the input numbers and I want to return the sum result between them on row 7 respectively across column B to F. I have the problem in specifying the content of the rows that are input for adding and therefore, I am getting an error. I was thinking to start by making artificial loop for rows (which is only one row) and then, loop through the columns. I am getting error when defining rows for input numbers i.e. values for row 4 and 6.

```
Sub SumCol()
Dim StartRow As Integer, EndRow As Integer, answer As Integer, FirstInput As Integer, FirstInputRow As Integer, SecondInput As Integer, SecondInputRow As Integer

Dim ColumnNo As Integer, TargetRow As Integer
Const COLUMNSTART As Integer = 2
Const COLUMNEND As Integer = 6

TargetRow = 7
EndRow = 7
FirstInputRow = 3
SecondInputRow = 6
FirstInput = Cells(FirstInputRow, ColumnNo)
SecondInput = Cells(SecondInputRow, ColumnNo)

For StartRow = TargetRow To EndRow
    For ColumnNo = COLUMNSTART To COLUMNEND
    answer = FirstInput + SecondInput
    Cells(TargetRow, ColumnNo).Value = answer
    Next ColumnNo

    TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
Next StartRow

End Sub
```

Can anybody help ?

Comment: You use `FirstInputRow` and `ColumnNo` variables as cells addresses before assign them any values... Maybe you should consider trying to simplify your code a little bit. It seems a lot of variables for such a simple task.

Comment: I have added defined variables for FirstInputRow and SecondInputRow because it needed to be omitted when writing the question, but it still does work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple like

```
Sub SumCol()
    For x = 2 To 6
        Cells(7, x).FormulaR1C1 = Cells(4, x).Value + Cells(6, x).Value
    Next x
End Sub
```

won't solve your problem? Simple enough!! Or maybe I didn't understand exactly your goal...